# Get Numbers from file name

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I am trying to get date from  file name, so I built this reg ex expression, but I am getting 136413 instead of 6413 , how can I tell this script to skip the numbers associated to FY like FY13. so that my end result should like this 642013 not 13642013 .

Thanks in advance.

```
string input = "X_X_FY13_Template_X_6 4 13_V2.xlsx";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Comment: Will the format for your "string input" be the same every time?

Comment: Yes sir , if not we will send it back to business :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your date is the only aspect that has whitespace, you can do this

```
string input = "X_X_FY13_Template_X_6 4 13_V2.xlsx";
string result = input.Split('_').Where(x => x.Contains(' ')).FirstOrDefault();
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty)
   result = result.Replace(" ","");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're not specifically tied to regex, you could do something like this:

```
var input = "X_X_FY13_Template_X_6 4 13_V2.xlsx";
var chunks = input.Split(' ', '_'); // any separator characters
var numChunks = chunks.Where(chunk => chunk.All(char.IsDigit));
var result = String.Concat(numChunks);
```

It'd probably be easier to read/maintain in the long run than all the look-aheads/look-backs.

**Edit:** Since you're after the date (as long as you're willing to accept the I18N risk)...

```
var date = String.Join("/", numChunks);
```

Comment: Excellent answer! @user1570210 - This would remove all numbers that are "mixed in" with no-digit characters, per underscore-separated string, which I think is the more general form of what you'd like to do.

Comment: Maybe you could also split only on the underscores, but modify the `IsDigit` check to allow spaces too. I'm not familiar enough with C#, but maybe it'd be as simple as `chunk.All(char.IsDigit|char.IsSpace)`.

Comment: @acheong87: You could use `chunk.All(c => char.IsDigit(c) || char.IsWhitespace(s))` to do what you're describing

Answer (score 2):

i would try to match a whole date with @"((\d{1-2}).(\d{1-2}).(\d{2-4}))"

take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/az24scfc.aspx#quantifiers
And remember the dot means any char.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(FY\d+)?(V\d+)?[^\d]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probably:

```
var result = string.Concat(input.Skip(10).Where(Char.IsDigit));
```

But this is a brittle solution (the `Skip(10)` is hardcoded) so the solution from Andrew above is better, I think.

Comment: Your answer gives exactly the output that he says is not what he's looking for.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce Fixed (added `Skip()`)

Answer (score 1):

```
        string input = "X_X_FY13_Template_X_6 4 13_V2.xlsx";

        Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\d* \d* \d*)");
        Match match = reg.Match(input);
        Group group = match.Groups[1];

        string result = group.Value;
```

the result variable will has `6 4 13` value.